# Xquery: find value closest to given number

Tags: xml, xquery

I'm trying to get the ratio closes to 1, but I cannot seem to be able to find how to do it... This is my code so far:

```
<testadvarden> 
   {for $i in 0 to 72
   let $latitude := $i
   let $iterad := (local:distance(data($latitude)))
   return <lista latitud = "{$latitude}" ratio = "{$iterad}" /> }
</testadvarden>
```

My function distance only returns the ratio. These are the most relevant return values:

```
<testadvarden>
  <lista latitud="26" ratio="1.210681245514598"/>
  <lista latitud="27" ratio="1.1472684079724134"/>
  <lista latitud="28" ratio="1.108013683878131"/>
  <lista latitud="29" ratio="1.0367234044480529"/>
  <lista latitud="30" ratio="0.9820439101177922"/>
  <lista latitud="31" ratio="0.8714211421572755"/>
  <lista latitud="32" ratio="0.7316921947582108"/>
</testadvarden>
```

So my problem is how to get the given latitud for the ratio closest to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would a sort on `abs(1 - @ratio)` give the closest one?

You could further process your `lista` elements with e.g.

```
for $l in */lista
order by abs(1 - $l/@ratio) ascending
count $pos
where $pos = 1
return data($l/@latitud)
```

At https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWVa that returns `30`. Instead of using `count/where` to identify the first/closest item in the sorted sequence you could also use `head`:

```
head(
  for $l in */lista
  order by abs(1 - $l/@ratio) ascending
  return $l
)/@latitud/data()
```

Instead of using `order by` to sort, in XQuery 3.1 with higher order/inline functions you could also use the `sort` function with e.g.

```
data(head(sort(lista, (), function($l) { abs(1 - $l/@ratio) }))/@latitud)
```

complete sample would be

```
declare context item := <testadvarden>
  <lista latitud="26" ratio="1.210681245514598"/>
  <lista latitud="27" ratio="1.1472684079724134"/>
  <lista latitud="28" ratio="1.108013683878131"/>
  <lista latitud="29" ratio="1.0367234044480529"/>
  <lista latitud="30" ratio="0.9820439101177922"/>
  <lista latitud="31" ratio="0.8714211421572755"/>
  <lista latitud="32" ratio="0.7316921947582108"/>
</testadvarden>;

data(head(sort(lista, (), function($l) { abs(1 - $l/@ratio) }))/@latitud)
```